# VK-Api keyboard not working whatever i do Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, vk

So i tried to make keyboard for quite some time but it don't work
main.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, json
from settings import *
import messageHandler


app = Flask(__name__)
#Проверка перезагрузки сайта
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hi there'

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def processing():
    #Распаковываем json из пришедшего POST-запроса
    data = json.loads(request.data)
    #Узнаём какой запрос мы получили от ВК
    if 'type' not in data.keys():
        return 'not vk'
    #Если подтверждение сервера
    if data['type'] == 'confirmation':
        return confirmation_token
    #Если новое сообщение
    if data['type'] == 'message_new':
        messageHandler.create_answer(data['object']['message'], token)
        return 'ok'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()`
```

api.py

```
import vk

session = vk.Session()
api = vk.API(session, v=5.103)

def send_message(peer_id, token, message, random_id, keyboard):
    api.messages.send(peer_id=int(peer_id), access_token=token, message=message, random_id=random_id)
```

messageHandler.py

```
import api
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id
import os
import importlib
from command_handler import command_list

def load_modules():
   # путь от рабочей директории, ее можно изменить в настройках приложения
   files = os.listdir("mysite/commands")
   modules = filter(lambda x: x.endswith('.py'), files)
   for m in modules:
       importlib.import_module("commands." + m[0:-3])

def get_answer(text):
    message = "Прости, я тебя не поняла, попоробуй написать 'помощь'."
    for c in command_list:
        if text in c.keys:
            message = c.process()
    return message


def create_answer(data, token):
    load_modules()
    peer_id = data['from_id']
    message = get_answer(data['text'].lower())
    random_id = get_random_id()    #int(round(time() * 100000))
    api.send_message(peer_id, token, message, random_id)
```

command_handler.py

```
command_list = []

class Command:
   def __init__(self):
       self.__keys = []
       self.description = ''
       command_list.append(self)

   @property
   def keys(self):
       return self.__keys

   @keys.setter
   def keys(self, mas):
       for k in mas:
           self.__keys.append(k.lower())

   def process(self):
       pass
```

command with keyboard

```
import command_handler

def info():
    message = "Приветствую вас в военно политической игре"
    return message

def keyboard():
    keyboard = {"one_time": True, "buttons": [[{"action": {"type": "text", "payload": "{\"button\": \"1\"}", "label": "Кнопка"}, "color": "positive"}, {"action": {"type": "text", "payload": "{\"button\": \"2\"}", "label": "Кнопка" }, "color": "positive"}]]}
    return keyboard

wpg_command = command_handler.Command()

wpg_command.keys = ['впи', 'цивка', 'wpg']
wpg_command.description = 'Позволяет поиграть в военно политическую игру'
wpg_command.process = info
```

i tried using many things like adding

```
self.keyboard = {}...
...
def keyboard(self):
    return self.keyboard
```

into command_handler but i am really bads with classes and made many changes in all these files but nothing happened with the exception of bot stopping working... pls help me